# How do I can specific multiple Google Maps Android API?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I've a android project where I use a Google Maps API. This is a team project so I need a numbers of API keys as how many members we are.

However I don't know how to define in **google_maps_api.xml** the total keys we have. Instead each member needs to write his key.

So I would like to know if it's possible to automate this: insert all keys and when any user run the project it will check all possible keys.

Comment: Why don't you synchronize the debug signing keystores instead, so all the developers can share the same debug API key?

Comment: I'd say, use the same API key for all developers...

Comment: @Fustigator I'd trying that but I got authorization failure. Before I tried this way I shared the project on Google Developers with my team, but with no success.

Comment: @CommonsWare How I do that?

Comment: Pick one `debug.keystore` file and copy it to all developer machines. See [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) for more about keystores.

Comment: Makes sense @CommonsWare. I'll try that. Thank you very much!

Comment: From the developers console you can get one unique api key for multiple signing keys.

Comment: Just one more question @CommonsWare: if I have another project with another team, doesn't it make some misconfused?

Comment: where i find that @mvai?

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot answer that.

Comment: Its ok @CommonsWare. Thanks anyway

Comment: @mvai thanks. I could resolv with that

Answer (score 0):

From Google Maps API v2 you can have a unique api key for multiple signing keys. This is useful in situations like yours, or when you will need to add the release key.

Assuming you are using the newest version of the site, go API Manager -> Credentials -> API keys. There you can add one line for each developer:

```
Package              Key
com.your.package     key1
com.your.package     key2 ...
```

[image]

Comment: can u please elaborate.... because the key1 and key2 are generated after the sha1 is provided.... Please explain how can we use multiple google APIs for a single application?